# SQL Union of 4 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 different tables:

- Address: address_id, postcode.
- Patient: address_id, name.
- FocusArea: geom.
- Postcode: geom, postcode.

I need to find the name of the patients that live within the focus area.

I have managed to get the postcodes where the patients live, and the postcodes within the focus area, but I don't know how to join both queries:

```
SELECT 
    air.address.postcode, air.patient.name
FROM 
    air.address 
INNER JOIN 
    air.patient ON patient.address_id = address.address_id;

SELECT 
    postcode as postcode
FROM 
    air.postcode, air.focusarea
WHERE
    air.focusarea.objectid = 1 
    AND ST_Intersects(air.postcode.geom, air.focusarea.geom);
```

`air.focusarea.objectid = 1` as there are different boundaries of the focus area.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Tania

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

```
select
   a.postcode, p.name
from air.address as a
    inner join air.patient as p on
        p.address_id = a.address_id
    inner join air.postcode as pc on
        pc.postcode = a.postcode
    inner join air.focusarea as fa on
        fa.objectid = 1 and
        ST_Intersects(pc.geom, fa.geom);
```

Comment: Hi Roman,I can see now what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much for your hekp